# Google Custom Search API error

Tags: google-api, google-custom-search, httpexception

I used Google Cloud Platform for Free trial 
https://cloud.google.com/free-trial/

to use custom search API in my java application

I write the following code in my application

```
 URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key="+key+ 
 "&cx=013036536707430787589:_pqjad5hr1a&q="+ qry + "&alt=json");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        (conn.getInputStream())));

String output;
System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");

while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {

    if(output.contains("\"link\": \"")){                
        String link=output.substring(output.indexOf("\"link\": \"")+("\"link\": \"").length(), output.indexOf("\","));

        System.out.println(link);       //Will print the google search links
    }     
}
conn.disconnect();
```

it some times gave me a result and after that it gave me the following error , and this error occurred regardless the query string

Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response   code: 403 for URL: https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=????&cx=013036536707430787589:_pqjad5hr1a&q=?????
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1839)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1440)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)

Where is the problem please?

Answer (score 0):

`403` is specifically Google's forbidden error - it means your sending too many requests too quickly and they think you using a bot or automation

If you load that query in your browser and watch the requests - keep hitting refresh quickly until you see an html response that says

```
We're sorry...

... but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request right now.

See Google Help for more information.
```